# How to Control Relative Size of Figures with Colorbar in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure, colorbar

I am trying to line up a plot of a signal with an image where the image has a colorbar. The colorbar causes the axes to be offset horizontally. 
My intuitive approach would be to fix the size of figures to something, like in Gnuplot with papersize. However, not sure which would be the best fit here.

### To Adjust Scaling to Square in Full Screen Mode of Matlab?

I want to maintain the relations between the two figures. I cannot use `squareform` in the first figure for some reason, while I can in the latter figure. 
Code

```
figure

ax2=subplot(2,2,2); 
plot(mat2gray(pdist(data, 'correlation')));
title('Corr pdist');
cbar2 = colorbar(ax2);
xlim([0 size(mat2gray(pdist(data, 'correlation')),2)]);
set(cbar2, 'Visible', 'off');

ax4=subplot(2,2,4); 
imshow(squareform( mat2gray(pdist(data, 'correlation')), 'tomatrix') ); 
colormap('parula'); colorbar;
title('Square Corr pdist');
```

Wrong Scaling in Output when Full Screen Mode of Matlab where you see the colorbar method is not sufficient for holding relations as proposed in the answer [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wzftU.png) about *How to Control Relative Size of Figures with Colorbar in Matlab?*

[image]

Right Scaling in Output when Default View

[image]

---

How can you maintain the square view of figures in the Full Screen Mode of Matlab?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would simply create a colorbar for the top axes as well and set the visibility to off.

```
figure;
ax1 = subplot(2,1,1);
ax2 = subplot(2,1,2);

cbar1 = colorbar(ax1);
cbar2 = colorbar(ax2);

set(cbar1, 'Visible', 'off')
```

[image]

The benefit here is that you will get consistent behavior when resizing the figures, etc. because the size and position of the two axes will be rendered in the same way.

The other thing you will need to remember is to keep the axes the same in all aspects. So for example if you have an image in the bottom axes (using `imshow`), MATLAB by default sets the axes to a square. To get your top plot to also be square you will need to use `axis square`. Then they will continue to line up.

```
axis(ax1, 'square')
```

[image]

Comment: @Masi I would close the other question as that is still part of this question. I have updated my answer to address this.

Comment: @Masi be sure to pass the correct axes handle. Based on your code it looks like it may be `ax2`

Comment: You are right! `axis(ax2, 'square');` works. Thank you for your answer!